# Input usável porém invisível

Tags: javascript, html

Preciso de um Input, em que eu consiga passar um valor para ele via javascript porém que ele fique invisível. tenho 3 valores fixos que sempre irei passar um deles, SAC, Distribuidor ou Consultor, mas como preciso enviar esses valores no formulário apenas para saber qual tipo de crud fazer no outro arquivo, gostaria de usar um input invisível.

Vou dar um exemplo do código atual, apenas seguindo a ideia do que uso hoje, a variável type por default é SAC, pegando ela eu adicionar o valor do input como sac..

```
<script>
 if(type=sac){
     $('#tipo').value('sac');
 }else if...

</script> 
<form action="page2">
 <input style="display: hidden;" id="tipo">
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<script>
 if(type=sac){
     $('#tipo').value('sac');
 }else if...

</script> 
<form action="page2">

 <input type="hidden" id="tipo"> <!-- Existe o input type "hidden", que é invisível -->
</form>
```

Mais um exemplo aqui:
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_hidden

Answer (score 1):

Existem alguns problemas no seu código, vamos lá:

Primeiro: A sua condicional está atribuindo um valor e não comparando ela, ou seja, se você precisa comparar você utiliza dois sinais de igual, assim `==`.

Segundo: Para passar o valor a um campo de `input` você deve utilizar o `.val(valorAqui)` e não o `.value()`.

Terceiro: Você pode aplicar o `display:none` para todos os campos que não serão exibidos e depois aplicar com o método `.value()` colocar o valor dentro do `input`.

Quarto: Pelo que vi você está utilizando o `Jquery` e como você usa o script antes do documento `html`, o que não é aconselhável, você **DEVE** colocar dessa maneira.

```
$(document).ready({
 //seu código aqui
})
```

Mas qual o motivo disso?

Dessa maneira você irá rodar o script somente quando o documento estiver pronto, assim ele não dará problemas, como não encontrar algum elemento que você quer manipular e ele nem foi carregado ainda.

Quinto: `display:hidden` é um atributo `html`que não existe você precisa utilizar o `display:none` ou utilizar o `type=hidden` no input.

Tendo isso em mente seu código irá rodar perfeitamente! :)

Answer (score 0):

Não só o tipo hidden no input, você pode também criar uma classe para ele ficar invisível.

```
.input-hidden{
  height:0;
  width:0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  float:right;
}
```

além do `display: none;` que é um atributo bastante utilizado também.